# No version symbols in freshly compiled libstdc++

Tags: gcc, symbol-table

I'm compiling version 10.1 of GCC using the following configuration:

```
../configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/user/toolchain/gcc  --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --enable-shared --enable-gnu-unique-object --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
```

After compilation is finished it seems i don't have any version symbols in the compiled listdc++.so:

```
> strings ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | grep GLIBCXX
  GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
  GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

(and nothing else)
(btw I get the same result if I 'make install' gcc before checking on the installed lib)

Going to another system, the same command issues (output truncated):

```
> strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
[ ... ]
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
[ ... ]
```

Why am I not getting the version symbols in my freshly new compiled gcc/libstdc++ version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found the error,
when configuring GCC for the system, i found this in the config.log
of libstdc++v3:

```
configure:74963: WARNING: === Linker version 2501 is too old for
configure:74965: WARNING: === full symbol versioning support in this release of GCC.
configure:74967: WARNING: === You would need to upgrade your binutils to version
configure:74969: WARNING: === 21400 or later and rebuild GCC.
configure:74971: WARNING: === Symbol versioning will be disabled.
```

Compiling a newer version of (binutils) ld and rebuilding gcc with it did the trick.